# Android Robotium Recorder load recorded test

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I am using the free trial version of Robotium Recorder. After a successful test recording Robotium Recorder added a module with my tests.

How can I modify a newly created test by the Robotium Recorder ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [user guide](http://robotium.com/pages/user-guide):

> To see the saved test case(s) expand the test project and look in the
>   src folder. The whole test project or a specific test case can be
>   executed by right clicking it and selecting Run As > Android JUnit
>   Test.

Answer (score 1):

@kevinpelgrims

Thanks for your answer. The main question was, if I can load a recorded test to the recorder and modify it there.

> "Currently its not possible to edit it through Robotium Recorder. We
>   are currently looking into adding a feature to load the tests into
>   Robotium Recorder to make it possible to edit them that way as well."
>
> by Robotium Support